# Little Healer - Dreamrunner Truemaging

Tags: android, little-healer

I'm having an extremely difficult time with the Dreamrunner Truemaging encounter.

It seems like my heals aren't even touching the dragons health by the time the raid DPS is terminal.

I'm decursing the heal effect on units once they're capped at max HP. Then for grins I've tried spamming every spammable spell directly on the dragon but have barely noticed the bar budge before the whole raid is unsustainable.

Is there a specific configuration I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was really tricky, but the method I used seems to be the only way possible.

I used flash heal, dispel, prayer of mending, and divine hymn.

Pretty much spam the crap out of prayer since it will smart heal 5 people (jump to the lowest) while waiting for the buff to get applied to everyone in the group.

Only dispel the buff when you are about to run out of mana since it gives you a bunch of mana back. Once the buff is on everyone I started to dispel one buff at a time, wait for it to get re-applied and repeat.

Eventually the damage got high enough that a raider would die during the cool down between dispel and the cast for flash heal. Around that time is when heal spells would finally start to make a dent on the dragon. At that point only dispel if you need the mana.

Comment: You are a beautiful person! That worked perfectly. I only used Hymn once though, I wonder if a well timed use of spirit healer (whatever that angel icon is lol) would help keep a decursed unit from dieing long enough to get rebuffed. But thank you so much!